# Can't find untested extension in order to remove it: SafariTabSwitching

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extensions

[image]

I don't need this extension anymore because Safari 9 has this feature built-in, but I can't find it anywhere to disable or remove it. It's not listed in my Preferences -> Extensions. I looked through my ~/Library/Safari/Extensions but it's not listed there either.

How do I remove this extension so that I don't get this annoying popup every time I launch Safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, Safari plugins should be in `/Library/Internet Plug-ins/`

[image]

However, I discovered SafariTabSwitching is actually in a different location

*Source : [Safari Tab Switching FAQ](http://hackemist.com/SafariTabSwitching/#faq)*

> **How to uninstall?**
>   Remove this file: `/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins/SafariOmnibar.bundle`
>   Alternatively you may [download this uninstaller](https://github.com/downloads/rs/SafariOmnibar/Safari%20Omnibar%20Unstaller.zip) and run it. Note that uninstaller won't remove SIMBL Agent as you may use some other SIMBL plugin and we don't want to break them.

Comment: I don't see anything similar to SafariTabSwitching in "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Disabled Plugins" or in "/Users/kenny/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Disabled Plugins". I also recursively grepped the entire /Library and ~/Library trees for the text SafariTabSwitching.

Comment: I discovered it's a SIMBL  plugin. Answer revised accordingly